# IBM Worklight - "Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-waf

While testing a HTTP adapter procedure code generated by "Create Data object from service" using Worklight Application Framework editor,it generates the following error:

> Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please
>   supply a valid soap action.

This is the web service URL: http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL

Invocation result of procedure:

```
{
   "Envelope": {
      "Body": {
         "Fault": {
            "Code": {
               "Value": "soap:Sender"
            },
            "Detail": "",
            "Reason": {
               "Text": {
                  "CDATA": "Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.",
                  "lang": "en"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "soap": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2003\/05\/soap-envelope",
      "xsd": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema",
      "xsi": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2001\/XMLSchema-instance"
   },
   "errors": [
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Cache-Control": "private",
      "Content-Length": "500",
      "Content-Type": "application\/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
      "Date": "Mon, 28 Apr 2014 07:56:34 GMT",
      "Server": "Microsoft-IIS\/7.5",
      "X-AspNet-Version": "2.0.50727",
      "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET"
   },
   "responseTime": 1476,
   "statusCode": 500,
   "statusReason": "Internal Server Error",
   "totalTime": 1477,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Support for SOAP actions in the HTTP header is being considered for a future release of Worklight.

If you wish to invoke the generated adapter in Worklight Studio v6.1 you will have to modify the generated SOAP adapter and manually add the action header.

For instance, for invoking a *GetWeatherInformation* operation you can open the generated adapter JS file and add the following lines:

```
headers = headers || {};
headers.SOAPAction = 'http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetWeatherInformation';
```

to the *Weather_GetWeatherInformation* function just before the call to *invokeWebService* at the end of this function.